# facing issue in integrating the docusign api to my local corephp project

Tags: docusignapi, docusign-sdk

> $client_id = 'a24dade0-5698-4277-808f-627416bb71c9';
> $client_secret = 'my client secret';
> $redirect_uri = 'https://www.example.com/callback'; // Make sure this matches your DocuSign app's settings
> $authUrl = 'https://account-d.docusign.com/oauth/auth?response_type=code&scope=signature&client_id='.$client_id.'&redirect_uri='.$redirect_uri;
> $c_code = curl_init($authUrl);
> Set the request method to GET
> curl_setopt($c_code, CURLOPT_HTTPGET, true);
> Specify the expected response content type
> curl_setopt($c_code, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Accept: application/json'));
> curl_setopt($c_code, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
> curl_setopt($c_code, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true); // Follow redirects
> curl_setopt($c_code, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
> curl_setopt($c_code, CURLOPT_HEADER, true); // Include headers in the output
>
> Execute the cURL request
> $response = curl_exec($c_code);
> echo $status = curl_getinfo($c_code, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
> echo $finalUrl = curl_getinfo($c_code, CURLINFO_EFFECTIVE_URL);
> if ($response === false) {
> echo 'Error: ' . curl_error($c_code);
> exit;
> }
>
> Close the cURL session
> curl_close($c_code);
> echo $return_code = json_decode($response, true);
> echo $code = $return_code['code'];

Comment: Unfortunately your question is not clear. Use the [API logging](https://support.docusign.com/s/document-item?language=en_US&rsc_301&bundleId=jux1643235969954&topicId=poz1578456669909.html&_LANG=enus) feature to record what your script is sending to DocuSign. Then ask a **new question on StackOverflow**. Also see the [How to ask a question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) doc

Answer (score 1):

In order to help you better, you need to better formulate your question by following the steps Larry shared